# Using Python to copy the directory structure

Tags: python, file, copy

Is it possible to write a script in python to do the following thing.

```
Basic Operation : copy files with the proper directory structure.
```

Given a list of file names , the program should scan the directory, and copy the files in the directory to a destination directory maintaining the folder structre. This is something like 'Export file system by creating appropriate subfolders' functionality in eclipse.

Comment: Please mark correct answer, it will be helpful for other viewers also

Answer (score 7):

You can use [shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree).

**Update:** You can take a look at the [shutil.py source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/shutil.py) to see how it is implemented.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** I just saw that the question was to copy directory structure and files. My answer below is for directory structure only without files and python3 only as pointed out by yossi. I would still like to leave my answer as is and hope not to be downvoted.

I found the upvoted answer by silviubogan quite helpful in solving the problem (which I too, were faced with several times), so here's my approach:

`shutil.copytree()` accepts a `copy_function` so all you need is a copy function that does not copy files. Here is a slightly altered version of `shutil.copy2()` that does that:

```
def copy_dir(src, dst, *, follow_sym=True):
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
        dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
    if os.path.isdir(src):
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_sym)
        shutil.copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_sym)
    return dst
```

And then a call to `shutil.copytree(source, target, copy_function=copy_dir)` re-creates the folder and sub-folder structure from `source` at `target`.

Comment: shutil.copytree copy function only available on python 3

Comment: I just realized I'm not even answering the question properly. When I wrote my answer, I read the question so that only the dir structure should be copied and not the files, but in fact, files the question was for files and folders.